# Using UITableView to display each attribute of NSManagedObject dynamically

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift, core-data

I have a `UITableView` and an `NSManagedObject` and I want to display one attribute per cell in the `UITableView`, what is the best way to do that?

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to load the attribute for a given `IndexPath`.

Any ideas appreciated!

Comment: You can use NSFetchedResultsController's with for attributes? I thought it was only for entities

Answer (score 1):

Use the `entity` property of the NSManagedObject to get the NSEntityDescription for it.  Then use the `properties` property of the entity description to get an array of NSPropertyDescriptions.  Use that array as the basis for your tableview.  So use `indexPath.row` as the index to select the property description for a given row.  (You might want to filter this array to exclude relationships).

Each property description will have a `name` property: use that, together with `valueForKey:` on the original NSManagedObject to look up the value for the property with that name.